# F# custom append function

Tags: list, function, recursion, design-patterns, f#

I have a custom function that appends list2 to list1.

```
let append ls1 ls2 =
    let rec loop ls ls1 ls2 =
        match ls1, ls2 with
        | _, hd::tl -> 
            loop (hd::ls) ls1 tl
        | hd::tl, _ -> loop (hd::ls) tl ls2
        | _ -> ls
    loop [] ls1 ls2
```

It works fine. But the problem is when I call the function

```
let appended = append [1;2;3;4;5] [6;7;8;9;10]
```

Instead of returning `[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10]` it returns

```
[5;4;3;2;1;10;9;8;7;6]
```

It inverses both the lists.

Comment: And what is your question?
If it's about the wrong result then try think again, and remember that `hd :: tl` is like attach a `hd` to head of `tl`, not append to the end of it

Comment: The desired result is [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10]

Comment: How is this question different from yesterday's? Please see the answers there.

Answer (score 2):

Following code worked out for me

```
let rec append list1 list2 = 
   match list1, list2 with
    | hd::tl, _ -> hd::(append  tl list2)
    | _, hd::tl -> hd::(append list1 tl)
    | _ -> []
```

The output of following code is:

```
   let List1 = [1; 3; 5];
    let List2 = [7]
    printf "%A" append List1 List2
```

is

```
[1; 3; 5; 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the list.
One way to go to the solution is to think how a `rev` function would look like.
Here's a first attempt:

```
let rec rev lst =
    match lst with 
    | h::t -> (rev t)@[h]
    | [] -> []
```

This function reverses a list, but now let's do another version which uses an accumulator, this means that instead of using an empty list in the last line we will use an addition paramater:

```
let rec rev lst acc =
    match lst with 
    | h::t -> rev t (h::acc)
    | [] -> acc
```

So now we have to pass the empty list as a parameter:

```
rev [1..4] [];;
```

val it : int list = [4; 3; 2; 1]

You may wonder why do we need such a function, well this function is [tail recursive](https://www.google.ie/search?q=tail+recursive+function&oq=tail+recursive+function) but that's not your question, you're looking to append two lists. It turns out that this is 90% the function you're looking for.

If instead of passing an empty list you pass the second list:

```
rev [1..4] [5..8];;
```

val it : int list = [4; 3; 2; 1; 5; 6; 7; 8]

Quite close, but yes, the first list is reversed, ok but we have this function that can reverse lists, so let's reverse the first list:

```
rev (rev [1..4] []) [5..8] ;;
```

val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8]

Great, now this `rev` could be our `loop` function:

```
let append lst1 lst2 = 
    let rec rev lst acc =
        match lst with 
        | h::t -> rev t (h::acc)
        | [] -> acc
    rev (rev lst1 []) lst2
```

Which works as expected, but note that we're just calling twice our parameterized `rev` function. Hopefully you get an idea of how functional programming allows you to combine functions in order to solve different problems. In this case we're combining a function with itself.